# Modify existing code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just registered here and I'm in search for help. I am a newbie in programming, but I do have some basic knowledge in programming and I am eager to learn PHP and MySQL and such languages.

I need help modifying PHP code that displays data from database in separated div elements.

**Here is the code:**

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = $_REQUEST['upit'];

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='proizvodi'>";
    // output data of each row
     $result->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
            foreach($row as $key => $value){
                echo $value;
            }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
else {
    echo "<div class='search-query-none'><img src='index/no result.png' width='754' height='198' /></div>";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Now how should I modify the code so that it will display data from each column inside a div with a class name that holds the name of the column in database?

I kind of understand this piece of code, but I don't understand some keywords such as `fetch_assoc()` and so, but I will learnt them with time.

I would really appreciate if you could help me, and please tell me if you're missing some information, since this is my first question here and I will gladly update the question with necessary information. Thank you!

****EDIT**
Here's is the fix:**

```
        // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = $_REQUEST['upit'];

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<div class='proizvodi'>";
    // output data of each row
     $result->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
            foreach($row as $key => $value){
                echo "<div class='" . $key . "'>" . $value . "</div>";
            }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
else {
    echo "<div class='search-query-none'><img src='index/no result.png' width='754' height='198' /></div>";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: `fetch_assoc` is a function you can read more about it on the PHP site, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php. In your `foreach` the `$key` is your column name `$value` is your column's value. So move the `echo "<div class='row'>";` inside and add `id` to the `div` or create a whole new div in there.

Comment: Can you update your question and add what the new code does? Use this link to edit your question, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34568223/edit (or the `edit` link under the `tags`).

Comment: These two lines are not safe to run -> `$sql = $_REQUEST['upit']; $result = $conn->query($sql);` You would be allowing your database to be easily compromised.

Comment: I updated the code, and the following works.

I am not aware of that, but since this is the website for my school project, I don't think it is a big deal and my mentor told me it's ok to use it. Is it easily to be compromised because I am using "GET" method?

Comment: Please put back the original code in the question. How is someone supposed to understand the answers if the question no longer has the original problem in it?

Comment: You are right, I really didn't think this through. I apologize, I will return back the original code and add solution.

Comment: why this question has so many votes?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to move the `echo "<div class='row'>";` into the inside of the foreach loop; and then instead of class='row', you can say this:

```
echo "<div class='{$key}'>{$value}</div>";
```

or

```
echo "<div class='" . $key . "'>" . $value . "</div>";
```

(The first approach plops the variables' values straight down into the string; the second concatenates them - the effect is the same.)

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! I'm finally unstuck and can proceed with development.
Tho for some reason, the first code example just didn't work out, it did tho print out the divs correctly, but it simply wouldn't collaborate with my CSS.
The second one works.